IncompatibleClassChangeError with FusedLocationProviderClient in Flutter using Mapbox SDK using mapbox_gl, location packages
I'm encountering a java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when trying to use the **Mapbox SDK **in my Flutter application. The error occurs when the location component is enabled.
Here's the error log:
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:58)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:26)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProxy.requestLocationUpdates(LocationEngineProxy.java:34)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.onLocationLayerStart(LocationComponent.java:1439)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.enableLocationComponent(LocationComponent.java:1568)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(LocationComponent.java:551)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778): at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:58)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(11778): at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:26)
...
W/System.err(11778): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~Uc2d5PhXyY76iByozNyP2A==/com.example.nursing_application-SBQa6Z0gIqTYnNBH0zixQg==/base.apk)
Process name is com.example.nursing_application, not key_process

Packages
firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  mapbox_gl: ^0.15.0
  latlong2: ^0.9.1
  location: ^7.0.0

Complete Code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  double? nurseLong;
  double? nurseLat;
  LatLng? currentLatLog;

  // Mapbox variables
  late CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition;
  late MapboxMapController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    init();

    super.initState();
  }

  init() async {
    await initialzedLocationAndSave();
    _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: currentLatLog!, zoom: 15);
  }

  _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  Future<void> initialzedLocationAndSave() async {
    Location _location = Location();

    bool? _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus? _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await _location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    LocationData _locationData = await _location.getLocation();
    currentLatLog = LatLng(_locationData.latitude!, _locationData.longitude!);
    print("--------------");
    print(currentLatLog?.latitude);
    print(currentLatLog?.longitude);
    nurseLat = currentLatLog?.latitude;
    nurseLong = currentLatLog?.longitude;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mapbox Example'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
            child: MapboxMap(
              accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
              minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(14, 17),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_initialCameraPosition));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
      ),
    );
  }
}


What I've Tried:
Checked dependencies: Made sure that all dependencies are up-to-date.
Rebuilt the app: Cleaned and rebuilt the app, but the issue persists.
Checked the implementation: Verified that the Mapbox setup follows the documentation.
Mapbox and location packages work well separately, but when I use both of them together to show the user's current location on the map, it raises an IncompatibleClassChangeError

The problem here happens because android's location implementation plugin uses play-services-location dependency of version >= 21. On the other hand, mapbox-gl is relatively old (last version released more than 2 years ago) and uses play-services-location of version less than 21.
In version 21.0.0, FusedLocationProviderClient became interface which made it incompatible with previous versions of that library on both API and ABI levels.
There is not much you can do about that. You can play with versions of location and mapbox-gl, lowering location in particular. But I think it is not convenient. Also, it is possible to fork Mapbox-gl and update android plugin, but I can't estimate efforts needed for this.
From my point of view, best way is to migrate to official MapBox flutter package here: https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_maps_flutter
It is better because this package in active development and issue tracker seems alive, which makes me think that this project will live long and it is safe to depend on it.
